# Different results between "apply over groupbys" and Python's "for" loop

Tags: python, for-loop, apply

New to Python and am following examples in Chatper 4 of "Python Data Science Handbook".  The groupby('column').apply(defined_function) results appear to be different than the 'same' arithmetic used when iterating over the rows.  I want to understand why.

The dataframe is created by:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': range(6),
                   'data2': rng.randint(0, 10, 6)},
                   columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])
```

producing:

```
    key  data1  data2
0   A      0      5
1   B      1      0
2   C      2      3
3   A      3      3
4   B      4      7
5   C      5      9
```

A function is defined to normalize the column 'data1' by dividing its values by the sum of the values in column 'data2'.  The function is applied on a groupby basis:

```
def norm_by_data2(x):
    x['data1'] /= x['data2'].sum()
    return x

df.groupby('key').apply(norm_by_data2)
```

producing:

```
    key data1   data2
0   A   0.000000    5
1   B   0.142857    0
2   C   0.166667    3
3   A   0.375000    3
4   B   0.571429    7
5   C   0.416667    9
```

I tried producing the same logic by iterating over the rows with:

```
d2_sum = df.data2.sum()

for x in df.index:
    print(df.data1.loc[x]/d2_sum)
```

My example returns:

```
0.0
0.037037037037
0.0740740740741
0.111111111111
0.148148148148
0.185185185185
```

What accounts for the differences?

Comment: The sum in the example using `groupby` only uses those elements of `data2` which match the giben key, e.g. in the case of key `'A'` it only sums over those elements of `data2` which have the key `'A'`.

Comment: Thank you Christoph for helping me understand.